# Clang-tidy file: How to list the checks in multiple lines

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Right now I have a `.clang-tidy` file that includes a large list of checks and they all go in one line like this:

```
Checks: '-*,bugprone-*,-bugprone-narrowing-conversions, cert-*, -cert-err58-cpp, clang-analyzer-*,cppcoreguidelines-*,-cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions...'
```

Is there a way to list each check (enabled or disabled) in multiple lines for easier version control?

Right now I toggle word wrap and that helps editing, but it's very hard to diff in code reviews.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Checks:
'-*,'
'cert-*,etc-*,'
...
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can remove the single quotation marks and list all checks in a line-breaking comma separated list that starts with a `>` entry, constructing a `.clang-tidy` file as follows:

```
---
Checks: >
    -*,
    cert-*,
    etc-*,
    <additional checks ...>
...
```

As of [D30567: [clang-tidy] Fix treating non-space whitespaces in checks list](https://reviews.llvm.org/D30567) the leading whitespace on each new line are only for readability, and you may choose any *consistent* number of leading spaces (YAML).

Comment: Actually, the file is a YAML, so leading whitespace is not the word.  I used a tab to indent, and got an error (that's when I noticed this is a YAML).  So "any consistent number of leading spaces" is more appropriate.

Comment: @alx Thanks for the ping! I've updated the answer. Feel free to propose an edit to the answer if you'd like it further updated.

Comment: is there a way to add comments inbetween those lines? e.g. I want to describe why exactly particular check was enabled/disabled

Comment: @dfrib no, it's not possible to do `#` _inbetween lines of multiline string_. that's why i see people [commenting each check completely outside the string](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/main/.clang-tidy) as a way around. I don't like it, it forces me to duplicate name of each check, but it the best way I've found so far.

Comment: Really looks like clang-tidy's config format has been rushed out without much thought. It should clearly be defined as a sequence! Or were they afraid the minus symbol might make it confusing considering we may also have a minus before the check name to disable it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the back slash at the end of every line:

```
---
Checks: "-*,\
modernize-*,\
-modernize-use-trailing-return-type,\
misc-*,\
-misc-non-private-member-variables-in-classes,\
-misc-no-recursion,\
cppcoreguidelines-*,\
"
...
```